# Ionic- Notify the user when he reached a location in google map

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want the user get a notification message  when he is close to the location by 10 meters .

Assuming that i set  specific points/locations [latitude/longitude] in sqlite databse , so when a user get a close to some points his mobile should notify him .

[image]

How   could i do that , with Ionic/Angularjs ?